# How to remove the statusbar from the default wordpress editor?

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

How to remove the letter P from the default wordpress editor? Previously i have removed that P but now the entire code changed from the `class-wp-editor.php` file.

> [image: WordPress 3.9.1 WP_Editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up working for me, uses the tinyMCE init filter to remove the 'statusbar' entirely.

```
/** Edit TinyMCE **/
function myformatTinyMCE($in) {
    $in['statusbar'] = false;

    return $in; 
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

Even with CSS, I couldn't find a way to definitely remove the path but keep the status bar - here's the CSS option:

```
function my_theme_add_editor_styles(){
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .mce-path   {display: none!important;}
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

**EDIT**

Changed the hook from `init` to `admin_head` as `init` would cause widgets to auto close when you would drag them to the sidebar - strange occurrence.

Comment: but the entire status bar is removed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a mere indication of the HTML tag of the place where your cursor is. The "p" here stands for a "paragraph" tag.

`<p>Text here</p>` is a code that displays whatever you write in text format so that browsers can show it. If alternatively, you type something and make its style Heading 1 and then emphasis the cursor there, it will show a h1.

It's not something you can remove, it simply **indicates** the kind of text there is (or going to be, as in your case).

Comment: It is not like that, i have removed this P when i was using the wordpress 3.6 i have removed that letter P there is an option in the code, but after upgrading i couldn’t see that option

Comment: I don't think you should say something **can't** be done without some kind of proof.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question. I thought you were confused on what is that and thought it was something else that you've previously removed. I really didn't know that you know what that is and have removed it.